# why I'm getting function get() on a non-object in error when using codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

index_model.php is below:

```
<?php
class index_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function getVideo()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('videolar');
        return $query->result_array();
    }

}
?>
```

And index controller is below, too

```
<?php

class index extends CI_Controller {

        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        function index()
    {
                $this->load->model('index_model');
                $data['video'] = $this->index_model->getVideo();
        $this->load->view('index',$data);
    }
}
?>
```

When I call index controller it returns this error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in
>   /var/www/atlet/application/models/index_model.php on line 10

I set database in autoload.php.

> $autoload['packages'] = array('database');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [load the database in the `libraries` array](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/autoload.php#L70), not the `packages` array:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```